# facing following error in programme

Tags: java, netbeans

```
Apr 29, 2011 9:24:04 AM library.check_out jButton1ActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is closed
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.checkOpen(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:6646)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.next(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:1249)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems pretty clear: some code has called `next()` on a `ResultSet`, but the `ResultSet` has already been closed; this is not allowed. If you look at the next line or two of the stack trace, below where you've cut it off, it will tell you exactly where in your code the call to `next()` is being made.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda looks like whatever resultset you are trying to find doesn't exist (null) or you have already completed processing and had closed the resultset (closed).

Please supply additional context to the issue if you want a more specific answer since this question is extremely vague.